# Finite-State Machine implementation

Tags: c, function-pointers, fsm

I'm trying to implement Finite-State Machine in C and need it to be very fast.
So I decided to use function pointers as "states":

```
void *state1(void){ /* function body here */ }
void *state2(void){ /* ... */ }
void *state3(void){ /* ... */ }
```

Then, main FSM loop can be very simple:

```
void *(*fp)(void);
fp = state1;

while(fp)
    fp = fp();
```

There is a questions:

1) Is it possible to avoid using void pointer in function return types? Ideally state functions should have some typedef'ed type to ensure that in FSM will be used only functions with this type.

2) Traditional approach of implementing FSM in C is using enum for states and switch-based dispatcher loop, so comparing with function-pointers based implementation there is will be one indirection level. 
But I'm not sure, can there some issues with instruction-cache or branch prediction have a place? In other words, can there exist implementation that can outperform my solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Do I smell microoptimization? How many times a millisecond does the state machine need to run?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev some states is relatively large and slow, but some is very small and simple. Performance doesn't matter when FSM in one of "large" state, but small states must be performed as fast as possible.

Comment: Use one-hot encoded state machine if you want it to be fast. Your premature optimizations won't go a long way. You are better off writing readable, maintainable and extendable code that works. Also, for C++ - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a recursive type definition like this in C you need to use a `struct` somewhere along the line, because you can't "forward declare" typedefs.  For example, you can wrap the function pointer within a `struct`:

```
struct state {
    struct state (*func)(void);
};
```

Then in the loop:

```
struct state state = { state1 };

while (state.func) {
    state = state.func();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you might find an answer on your question: http://code.google.com/p/fwprofile/

It's an open source version (GNU GPLv3) of the state machine implemented 
in C. The concept and implementation is well-suited for use in 
mission-critical applications. There are deployments in industrial 
applications.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in C to declare a function which returns a pointer to a function of its own type. Moreover, you cannot use `void *` because C does not allow conversion between function and object pointers. Instead you can use:

```
typedef void (*generic_func_ptr)(void);
typedef generic_func_ptr (*state_func_ptr)(void);
generic_func_ptr state1(void), state2(void), state3(void);
state_func_ptr fp;

while(fp)
    fp = (state_func_ptr)fp();
```

Ugly, but it works. Instead, I would consider using a switch statement. It's a lot cleaner for implementing state machines.

Answer (score 0):

1) `typedef void(*state_fp)(void);`

```
state_fp state1(void) { }
```

2)     depends, a small loop with the code built into the function will be faster than making function calls.  eg, a switch statement where each state is implemented in the switch statement,  however, if there is too many case statements, this will degrade below function calls

Comment: This will require a cast on return, since the type returned by the function is not the same as the type of a pointer to the function itself (it's still better than the OP's, as at least you are casting from one function pointer type to another so it is well-defined).

Answer (score 0):

In case others want use a free framework for an fsm, please have a look at http://www.block-net.de/Programmierung/cpp/fsm/fsm.html
There is a C and C++ finite state machine framework including state chart generator with PlantUML.